# When passing the init_score parameter to lightgbm for binary targets, do I pass my initial predictions as probabilities or as logit values?

Tags: lightgbm

My understanding of GBMs, is that the trees in the GBM model/predict the logit (log odds) that is then wrapped in the logistic function to get the final probability prediction. Given this, it is unclear whether I should pass my initial prediction as probabilities or as logit values.

Also when I make predictions, do I sum my initial probability prediction with the GBM probability prediction, or do I convert both to logits and then use the logistic function on the summed logits predictions?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this [blog](https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/lightgbm-focal-loss/) will give you some idea.

It says `init_score` in the binary classification is calculated in this way:

```
def logloss_init_score(y):
    p = y.mean()
    p = np.clip(p, 1e-15, 1 - 1e-15)  # never hurts
    log_odds = np.log(p / (1 - p))
    return log_odds
```